# Is it possible to show only value in MySQL "show variables"?

Tags: mysql, variables

It is an easy task to find MySQL variable values:

```
mysql> show variables where Variable_name = 'version';
+---------------+--------------------+
| Variable_name | Value              |
+---------------+--------------------+
| version       | 5.0.19-Max         |
+---------------+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

But is there any syntax that allows to select only column with variable value, like so:

```
mysql> command_i_want_to_know
+--------------------+
| Value              |
+--------------------+
| 5.0.19-Max         |
+--------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 34, accepted):

One more variant -

```
SELECT @@version;
```

Answer (score 10):

```
select variable_value 
from information_schema.global_variables
where variable_name = 'version';
```

Comment: As written in the manual "The GLOBAL_VARIABLES and SESSION_VARIABLES tables were added in MySQL 5.1.12." So this does not work in 5.0 http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/variables-table.html

Comment: That's the way for 5.5 users, BTW my problem solved by @Devart.

Answer (score 0):

Complementing previous answers: depending on your MySQL version and settings, you will probably need this to make it work:

```
set @@global.show_compatibility_56=1;
```

You may also want to add this to your my.cnf, under the [mysqld] section:

```
show_compatibility_56 = 1
```